# How to Setup Angular 2 Project Properly

Tags: angular

I use the following sample project to learn Angular 2:

https://bitbucket.org/syncfusiontech/angular-2-succinctly/overview

I did the following things:

1. after `git clone https://bitbucket.org/syncfusiontech/angular-2-succinctly/overview` I executed the following commands:
2. `cd AsBook`
3. `npm install`
4. `npm start`

A new browser instance is opened, but remains with the message `Loading...`.

In the browser debug mode, I see the following errors:

`jquery.min.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
jquery.min.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
bootstrap.min.js:6 Uncaught ZoneAwareErrormessage: (...)name: (...)originalStack: (...)stack: (...)toSource: function ()toString: function ()zoneAwareStack: (...)__zone_symbol__error: Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery
    at http://localhost:3000/node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js:6:37 [<root>]get message: function ()set message: function (value)get name: function ()set name: function (value)arguments: (...)caller: (...)length: 1name: "set"prototype: Object__proto__: function ()[[FunctionLocation]]: zone.js:899[[Scopes]]: Scopes[4]get originalStack: function ()set originalStack: function (value)get stack: function ()set stack: function (value)get zoneAwareStack: function ()set zoneAwareStack: function (value)__proto__: Object
:3000/app/main.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
localhost/:23 ZoneAwareError
(anonymous) @ localhost/:23`

How do I have to correct the `package.json` file to set it up properly?

`package.json`:

`{ "name": "helloworld",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "First Angular-2 application",
  "author":"Joe Booth",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "tsc && concurrently \"npm run tsc:w\" \"npm run lite\" ",

    "lite": "lite-server",
    "postinstall": "typings install",
    "tsc": "tsc",
    "tsc:w": "tsc -w",
    "typings": "typings"
  },
  "license": "UNLICENSED",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "~2.3.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~2.3.0",
    "@angular/core": "~2.3.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~2.3.0",
    "@angular/http": "~2.3.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~2.3.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~2.3.0",
    "@angular/router": "~3.3.0",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.6",
    "systemjs": "0.19.39",

    "angular-in-memory-web-api": "~0.1.16",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.8",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-rc.4",
    "zone.js": "^0.7.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^3.0.0",
    "lite-server": "^2.2.2",
    "typescript": "^2.0.3",

    "typings": "^1.4.0"

  }
}`

Comment: I think your dependencies are not installed properly. Check the node_modules folder. If you are unable to find jquery, then explicitly install npm install bootstrap

Comment: only with `npm install jquery` I have been able to remove the jquery error. `npm install bootstrap` did not help. But still `:3000/app/main.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
localhost/:23 ZoneAwareError
` remains

Answer (score 0):

In index.html i see

```
<script src="node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Try execute

`npm i jquery --save`

Comment: thanks, but still I get a `:3000/app/main.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)`

Comment: thanks, but still the file `app/main.js` is not there. So there is a file `app/main.ts`, but it does not get transpiled to a `*.js` file.